# Average query size

Tags: mysql

I'm doing profiling on an application I've written and one thing that I want to know is the average query size. There are times when the app sends batch insert statements and one customer with a remote mysql server (from shared webhosting provider) had an extremely low max_allowed_packet config out of his control.

I've got the full query log enabled on a dev server but I'm having trouble finding any tool that reports the average query sizes, just so that I'm aware of what we're using. Also, any advice on good query log analyzers is appreciated too.

Comment: The size of a query statement, what would cause them to exceed the max_allowed_packet size setting.

Answer (score 0):

You could always divide the size of the query log file by the number of lines in the query log file to get a rough idea of your average size. What matters most is maximum, though.

Why don't you set `max_allowed_packet` to 1GB and not worry about it?

Comment: Because this is for an application that's distributed and nothing of my own control. Some users are on shared web hosts who set the max_allowed_packet to an unbearably low number, and I'd like to be informed before advising on a minimum setting. A line != one full statement because we use batch inserts, which are variable in length because it's emptying data that happens to be in a queue. Sometimes it's 5 inserts, sometimes it's 1000. We allow the user to change how many are sent in one batch, so that helps users who can't change the packet size setting.

Comment: If you want to be a hero you'd do a `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'` and use that information to construct your queries accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't convince a thousand people to do this on their mysql servers.

Comment: What I said was to read what the maximum size is and make your queries fit within that limit. It doesn't require any server changes.

Comment: Read what max size, what limit? The max_allowed_packet is determined by whoever runs the mysql server, and I have a thousand users who have very different mysql servers. Some self-host it and use defaults, but some use third party mysql servers that extremely limit the setting - some have it as low as 1MB. All I can do is run analysis on the queries so I know the average sizes are, for informational purposes. I can't ask 1000 people what their limits are.

Comment: If you know what the limit is, you can construct your queries accordingly. `SHOW VARIABLES` can be used to retrieve that information. Average query size will not matter when you're talking about maximum, right? The only way you're making a >1MB query is by doing bulk inserts, so stop adding things to that query when it would exceed the `max_allowed_packet` limit for that particular server.